# In bash, how to `eval` a function definition?

Tags: bash

I have the following function definition:

```
function get-set-def() {
  flag=$1
  varname=$2

  case "${flag}" in
    -a)
      type ${varname} | sed -e 's|^|eval \$(alias |' -e $'s| is aliased to \`|=\'|' -e 's|$|)|'
      ;;

    -f)
      type ${varname} | tail -n +2 | sed -e $'1{ s/^/function /; }' -e $'${ s/$//; }'
      ;;

    -v)
      echo ${!varname} | sed -e "s|^|eval \$(${varname}=|" -e 's|$|)|'
      ;;
  esac
}
```

which, for a function, `cdg` in this case, will output:

```
$ get-set-def -f cdg
function cdg () 
{ 
    cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/"$1"
}
```

but if I try to `eval` its output, I see:

```
$(get-set-def -f cdg)
bash: function: command not found
```

even though copying and pasting the output works fine:

```
$ function cdg () 
{ 
    cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/"$1"
}
$ type cdg
cdg is a function
cdg () 
{ 
    cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/"$1"
}
```

I've tried different combinations with `eval` (which for the cases I've tried, has worked for `alias`es and variables. What needs to be done to get this to work for functions?

Context: I know it seems strange to set things to what they already are. My plan is to save current settings so they may be reset later.

Comment: Try `eval "$(get-set-def -f cdg)"`

Comment: @Abelisto, it looks like that works but I would like callers not to have to do that.

Comment: @Abelisto, `type ${varname} | tail -n +2 | sed -e $'1{ s/^/eval \'function /; }' -e $'${ s/$/\'/; }'` looks like it works. I thought I had tried that but must've had a typo somewhere. If you'd like to post that answer, I'll vote it up.

Comment: Why not simply `declare -f cdg` ??

Comment: `get-set-def -f cdg` just `declare -f cdg`. `sed -e $'1{ s/^/function /; }' -e $'${ s/$//; }'` why do you do that? Remove it.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I didn't use `declare -f` is because I didn't know about it.

Comment: Huh, when I try `echo "eval '$(declare -f ${name})'"` and other variants, `$(get-set-def -f cdg)` emits `cdg () { cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/"$1" }: No such file or directory`. Without the `eval`, the result is `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @Abelisto, my mistake. `type ${varname} | tail -n +2 | sed -e $'1{ s/^/eval \'function /; }' -e $'${ s/$/\'/; }'` actually has similar errors as when using `declare -f`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the various comments, `echo "echo $(declare -f ${name}) | source"` works.

Likewise `echo "echo $(alias ${name}) | source"` for `-a` and `echo "echo $(echo ${name}=${!name}) | source"` for `-v` work.

Altogether, the function becomes:

```
function get-set-def() {
  flag=$1
  name=$2
  
  local def
  case "${flag}" in
    -a)
      def="$(alias ${name})"
      ;;
    
    -f)
      def="$(declare -f ${name})"
      ;;
    
    -v)
      def="$(echo ${name}=${!name})"
      ;;
  esac

  echo "echo ${def} | source"
}
```